# LALR parsing : retrieve the grammar rules from the generated parsing tables

Tags: decompile

I have a quite old C corporate parser / compiler code that was generated from an ancient Yacc and the original grammar source is lost (as the intermediate files) the only result the `ytab.c` parser generated file. That legacy piece of code need revamping but I cannot afford to recode it from scratch.

By "ancient Yacc", I mean that the parser is using tables named `yyact`, `yypact`, `yypgo`, `yyr1`, `yyr2`, `yytoks`, `yyexca`, `yychk`, `yydef`.

Could it be possible to mechanically retrieve / regenerate the parsing rules by deduction of the parsing tables in order to reconstruct the grammar?

Example with a little sample of an expression parser that I can process with the same ancient Yacc:

```
yytabelem yyexca[] ={
-1, 1,
    0, -1,
    -2, 0,
-1, 21,
    261, 0,
    -2, 8,
    };
yytabelem yyact[]={

    13,     9,    10,    11,    12,    23,     8,    22,    13,     9,
    10,    11,    12,     9,    10,    11,    12,     1,     2,    11,
    12,     6,     7,     4,     3,     0,    16,     5,     0,    14,
    15,     0,     0,     0,    17,    18,    19,    20,    21,     0,
     0,    24 };
yytabelem yypact[]={

  -248, -1000,  -236,  -261,  -236,  -236, -1000, -1000,  -248,  -236,
  -236,  -236,  -236,  -236,  -253, -1000,  -263,  -245,  -245, -1000,
 -1000,  -249, -1000,  -248, -1000 };
yytabelem yypgo[]={

     0,    17,    24 };
yytabelem yyr1[]={

     0,     1,     1,     1,     2,     2,     2,     2,     2,     2,
     2,     2,     2 };
yytabelem yyr2[]={

     0,     8,    12,     0,     6,     6,     6,     6,     6,     6,
     4,     2,     2 };
yytabelem yychk[]={

 -1000,    -1,   266,    -2,   259,   263,   257,   258,   267,   262,
   263,   264,   265,   261,    -2,    -2,    -1,    -2,    -2,    -2,
    -2,    -2,   260,   268,    -1 };
yytabelem yydef[]={

     3,    -2,     0,     0,     0,     0,    11,    12,     3,     0,
     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,    10,     1,     4,     5,     6,
     7,    -2,     9,     3,     2 };

yytoktype yytoks[] =
{
    "NAME", 257,
    "NUMBER",   258,
    "LPAREN",   259,
    "RPAREN",   260,
    "EQUAL",    261,
    "PLUS", 262,
    "MINUS",    263,
    "TIMES",    264,
    "DIVIDE",   265,
    "IF",   266,
    "THEN", 267,
    "ELSE", 268,
    "LOW",  269,
    "UMINUS",   270,
    "-unknown-",    -1  /* ends search */
};
```

I am looking to retrieve

```
stmt    : IF exp THEN stmt
        | IF exp THEN stmt ELSE stmt
        | /*others*/
        ;

exp     : exp PLUS exp
        | exp MINUS exp
        | exp TIMES exp
        | exp DIVIDE exp
        | exp EQUAL exp
        | LPAREN exp RPAREN
        | MINUS exp
        | NAME
        | NUMBER
        ;
```

The full parser for this example is available [as a gist](https://gist.github.com/sebkirche/7896350), it is showing a `yyreds` table containing the rules as a debug info that is not in the parser that I am trying to reverse.

Note : I have asked this [formerly on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20496216/317266), and was suggested to ask it in RE. Any help?

PS: i am not familiar with the RE question tags, feel free to correct this.

Comment: Please see the edit :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't have an actual answer. I've heard some rumors of a tool doing that but haven't seen anything concrete. I have, however, found a page which should be pretty helpful:

> #### Understanding C parsers generated by GNU Bison
>
> This document is an attempt to describe the implementation of an
>   LALR(1) parser in C as generated by Bison 2.3. I used a simple grammar
>   to demonstrate the working of the parser and the nature of parsing
>   tables. You will also find a comparison of these tables to the
>   uncompressed tabular scheme given in the popular book "Compilers -
>   Principles, Techniques and Tools" by Aho, Sethi and Ullman, also
>   called as the "Dragon Book" and many other books on compiler design.

See it [here](http://www.cs.uic.edu/~spopuri/cparser.html).

**EDIT**: found a script that claims to do it!

http://nah6.com/~itsme/cvs-xdadevtools/perlutils/yydecode.pl

However it seems it's intended to be used with another set of tables. Still, it might be useful for a start.